# Run function in another thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So say there are two running codes: script1 and script2.
I want script2 to be able to run a function in script1.
script1 will be some kind of background process that will run "forever".

The point is to be able to make an API for a background process, E.G. a server.

The unclean way to do it would be to have a file transmit the orders from script2. script1 would then execute it with `exec()`. However, I would like to use a module or something cleaner because then I would be able to output classes and not only text.

EDIT: example:

script1:

```py
def dosomething(args):
    # do something
    return information
while True:
    # Do something in a loop
```

script2:

```py
# "import" the background process
print(backgroundprocess.dosomething(["hello", (1, 2, 3)]))
```

The execution would look like this:

1. Run script1
2. Run script2 in a parallel window

Comment: Without some more context on specifically what kind of processes you're using its hard to give any feedback.

Comment: What is script1 and script 2. What function you want to execute, what are your inputs .. I have a lot of doubts :-) Help me to help you!

Comment: how do you plan to communicate between two completely separate processes? this is not even about threads, you have completely different processes if you run each file separately. What you seem you could do is send a request to the server and the server has some functions in it already defined and likely put in a dictionary with string keys, so the request sends this string key and the server then just calls a function from the dictionary (likely with some additional arguments also given by the request)

Comment: @Matiiss That's exactly my question: is there a way to communicate with a process that was started before? As I said the best way I know would be to use exec() in script1 and then print the output in a file.

Comment: @tarneo that is not a way to communicate, `exec` could be used after you have communicated, a way to communicate would be through networking or perhaps files, but if you have a server you can just use the networking, basically `flask` for server side and `requests` for client side (they can both do it locally if you need)

Comment: @Matiss Just to clarify: server and client are software-side, not different hardware. I'll try to make a module with socket until I have a better way.

Comment: @tarneo yes, I forgot, sockets are also a good approach, maybe even simpler than using web frameworks. I understand that you need them to be on one hardware but still you can communicate on the local network, maybe files can also be used but I can't currently think of how to handle two processes interacting with the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

The [XMLRPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example) modules are designed for this purpose.

The docs include a worked out example for a server (script1) and a client (script2).

### Server Example

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
with SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8000),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
    server.register_introspection_functions()

    # Register pow() function; this will use the value of
    # pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
    server.register_function(pow)

    # Register a function under a different name
    def adder_function(x, y):
        return x + y
    server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

    # Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
    # published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'mul').
    class MyFuncs:
        def mul(self, x, y):
            return x * y

    server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

    # Run the server's main loop
    server.serve_forever()
```

### Client Example

```
import xmlrpc.client

s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8000')
print(s.pow(2,3))  # Returns 2**3 = 8
print(s.add(2,3))  # Returns 5
print(s.mul(5,2))  # Returns 5*2 = 10

# Print list of available methods
print(s.system.listMethods())
```

Comment: Just thought of another way to do this: we could store tasks within a file and then use the system signals to tell the other program "hey, i've sent you something to do!" (using the `signal` library)

Comment: Even better: use a file and then just inotify to watch for changes... once the file is closed (event `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`), run the actions that have been stored in it.